# Pygtk how to move window out of screen

Tags: window, gtk, pygtk

I have ubuntu 12.04 on gnome and trying to move basic window in pygtk out of screen.
I need to slide in window from right of screen. Problem is that window manager won't let me do that, as soon as it reach right edge it stops moving.

Is there some settings that says to window manager that I need to be able to go out of screen.
Same window could be moved out of screen manually.

Comment: 'Moving a window out of screen' is an odd use-case. Can you give details on what you're actually trying to implement?

Comment: I actually want to have some animation, to slide my app window from right hand side. Only other way it to moving and resizing my window at the same time.

Comment: To be honest: this is a task of the window manager. Or of an advanced graphics library that renders this kind of animation. Maybe you could implement fading as an alternative: [`gtk_window_set_opacity`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.5/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-opacity)

Comment: Is there a way to say to wm how to handle my window. gtk.Window have property_change method, is that how I can tell wm that I'm gonna use animations and docking and so?

Comment: I don't think so. Try to think of an opensource project that has such animations and look at their source code or contact the developers. If you can, add an answer to this question to share your gained knowledge.

Comment: It depends on wm, for example fluxbox will allow you to do this. Maybe there is some property for other wm-s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resize the window instead of moving it.

Comment: If you must have this feature, this works but it's not really best approach.

Comment: I agree, using a WM that supports it would be better.